# TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified in Powershell script after migrate from Windows 7 to Windows 8

Tags: oracle, powershell, tns

I have a Powershell script that perform some tasks based on a Oracle query result.

Recently I had my box replaced with a brand new laptop with Win 8 and now when I try to run the same powershell script that I used to use it is not working.

Now I got a error message in Powershell:

```
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
"
At C:\Users\User1\Desktop\BatchRun\ESS-QUEUE.ps1:146 char:5
+     $connection.Open()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OracleException

Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "Invalid operation. The connection is closed."
At C:\Users\User1\Desktop\BatchRun\ESS-QUEUE.ps1:147 char:5
+     $users = $command.ExecuteReader()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\User1\Desktop\BatchRun\ESS-QUEUE.ps1:157 char:12
+     while ($users.Read()) {
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I figure out that Oracle Client was missing so I had managed to have TOAD Express working and also the Oracle Client 10R2 (32 and 64). That said I can actually run the sqlplus.exe and TOAD without problem.

Could anyone give me a hint how to solve this issue and make my script work again?

Comment: We would probably need to see the lines in the actual script, as defined in the error output above.  Be sure to provide a [mcve], if at all possible, please.  The data in the error specifying: `.ps1:146`, for example, signifies the line number in the script.  We would need to see a good bit before that line, most likely, or you would need to "fill in the blanks" we can't/not allowed to see.

Comment: Use the TNSPING utility that comes with Oracle client. From cmd prompt, you should be able to do `TNSPING name_of_database` and it will show if it can resolve the name and connect correctly.

Comment: Hi @gravity... I can guarantee to you that line 146 doesn't contain any logical/typing error. The script was working in the past... problem reside the fact that because the OS update my script stop working and start return these errors. I've tried reinstall Oracle Clients, both 32 and 64... no luck yet.

Comment: Hi @PeterM. I've tried that. TNSPING is actually returning the string connection line as (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=HOST.ADRESS.COM)(PORT=1234567))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MYNAME))) when I try TNSPING MYNAME. What I notice that sqlnet.ora is pointing to a network drive and not reading from oracle install folder (maybe because it's how the company that i'm working for configured that way).

Comment: I was able to make it work again after this post (since it from 2016) but recently I start getting the same error message again and I'm not able to fix it. I will keep counting with the Stackoverflow community to get this resolved.

Comment: You could try ezconnect syntax. It would save you having to get the underlying configuration files right.

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/EZCONNECT